How to create a standalone project
I had never used standalone before. And now I wanted to try.
I created a new project using the command:
ng new client --style=scss --standalone

And when I tried to run the project, I get a blank page with an error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

I didn't make any changes to the project.
I'm using:
"@angular/cli": "^16.2.15",
"typescript": "^5.1.3"

Why does it give an error right when the "hello world" page starts?
main.ts:
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

app.config.ts:
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes)]
};



how do you run the project ?

@Pac0 npm run start

Hm, weird. Do you know where the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' comes from? Maybe this specific version of @angular/cli had some problem creating projects, too.
